# Are SQL views anything more than saved text?

Tags: view, dbms

I am trying to get a better understanding of an answer by @GarethD in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188350/incorrect-syntax-near-keyword-option-in-cte-statement?rq=1#answer-24188586 . In that answer he states:

> If you think of a view more as a stored subquery than a stored query … and remember that its definition is expanded out into the main query …

this seems to imply that a view is more-or-less a saved string which is inserted as a subquery at the right spot. In the context of the answer it was to explain why a view in SQL Server can’t include hints, because you can include them in subqueries.

I know that DBMSs are free to do things their own way, and that it may not *literally* be as I described, but it seems to boil down to the same.

Is this a correct understanding of views? Would this also apply to Table Valued Functions, which are effectively parameterised views?

Does this vary from DBMS to DBMS. That is, do some DBMSs add more features to views?

Comment: You seem to be asking two separate types of questions. SQL Server specific questions and DBMS Comparison question. I would focus on the SQL Server specific questions (and tag that RDBMS). Just looking at [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16638/hintsref.htm) suggests that each DBMS can handle a `VIEW` differently (with respect to hints)

Comment: @MichaelKutz The quote comes from a discussion on SQL Server, but I wanted to know whether all DBMSs treat views as injected virtual strings.